Django collectstatic Error: MissingFileError for a File That Exists with Correct Name and Path
I'm encountering a MissingFileError while running collectstatic in my Django project. The error message is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Path\To\Project\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Path\To\Project\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 154, in collect
    raise processed
whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'background_image_nislex8.jpg' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x000002CCDD5DE500>.

The CSS file 'styles.css' references a file which could not be found:
  background_image_nislex8.jpg

Please check the URL references in this CSS file, particularly any
relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.

I'm getting this error despite having changed the name of the file to background_image_nislex.jpg and updating the reference in the styles.css file to the same name.
How can I resolve this issue and ensure that collectstatic recognizes the updated file name?
What I've Tried:

Verified that the file background_image_nislex.jpg exists in the correct directory.
Updated the reference in the styles.css file to match the new filename.
Cleared the cache and tried running collectstatic again, but the error persists.

Environment:

Django Version: 3.x
Python Version: 3.10
Static Files Storage: whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage


Have you tried running python manage.py collectstatic --clear --noinput ?
